# BufferedImage inconsistent behavior

Tags: java, image, image-processing, awt, bufferedimage

After I set a pixel of a java.awt.image.BufferedImage to a value using setRGB, a subsequent call to getRGB returns a different value than I set.

Code:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
int color1 = -16711423; // corresponds to RGB(1, 1, 1)
image.setRGB(0, 0, color1);
int color2 = image.getRGB(0, 0);
System.out.println(color1);
System.out.println(color2);
```

It produces the following output

```
-16711423
-16777216
```

I think it has to do something with gamma correction, but I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation.

Ideally, I want to change this behavior to return the same value as I set. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `BufferedImage.getRGB()` method, always returns a color (as an `int` in "packed format") in the *non-linear* **sRGB** color space (`ColorSpace.CS_sRGB`). It will do so, regardless of what color space and bits per pixel etc. your image has. Thus, conversion and possible precision loss may occur.

From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB(int,%20int)):

> Returns an integer pixel in the default RGB color model (TYPE_INT_ARGB) and default sRGB colorspace. Color conversion takes place if this default model does not match the image ColorModel.

Your `TYPE_BYTE_GRAY` image internally uses a *linear* gray color space (`ColorSpace.CS_GRAY`), which does not map one-to-one with sRGB.

Also, I suggest using hexadecimal notation for (A)RGB colors, it makes the colors and difference much easier to see:

```
-16711423 == 0xff010101
-16777216 == 0xff000000
```

So, there is a minor precision loss here, but nothing unexpected.

If you want direct access to the pixel data, look into the `Raster`, `SampleModel` and `DataBuffer` classes (and their respective subclasses).

Answer (score 0):

You set a color specified with an `int` which stores RGB components as bytes (in the range of 0..255 inclusive).

But the color model of your image is not RGB but `BYTE_GRAY`. Obviously you may suffer precision losing. This explains the different colors. Should you have used image type `TYPE_INT_RGB` you would've ended up with the same color.